# Good Design Principles: Where to put text processing code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have a situation where I have to do a lot of text processing on data before I use the processed text to create an object instance. The question I have is whether it is better oop design to do the text processing first, and then create the object instance, or pass the unprocessed text to the object constructor and do it there. Basically:

Method 1:

```
lots_of_text = "................."

class_properties = process_text(lots_of_text)

newobject = MyObject(class_properties)
```

Method 2:

```
newobject = MyObject(lots_of_text)
```

It seems like a trivial question when both would work, but when the text processing in reality can be hundreds of lines of code, I think it is worth considering. Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: What I like to do in a case like this is code a simple example both ways, and see which ends up looking cleaner to me. There isn't always one right approach, and until you actually write out some code it probably won't be obvious - to you or others - which works out better.

Comment: This question is too generic and sketchy to answer in objectively. Instead of asking this generic question, I suggest that you post real working code for open-ended critique on [codereview.se], and mention this as a minor concern (among other issues that you might want to raise). Be sure to read [How to Ask](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting there.

Answer (score 0):

When coming up with the design, consider the separation of responsibilities. Is text processing the responsibility of `MyObject`? Does it ever need contents of `lots_of_text`, except to process it in the constructor? (Could it ever make sense to defer processing for later, e.g. for performance reasons?) If the answer to these questions is "no", then text processing does not belong to `MyObject`.